# Why does my code run twice when used outside of the useEffect()?

Tags: reactjs

I am using a websocket that emits a string when the page is loaded. When i use this code outside of the useEffect() the code is runs twice. It spits out "world" twice. But when i add it to the useEffect() it is ran once. Just wondering why it is run twice outside of the useEffect hook. Below is my code. Thank in advance!

```
 function App() {
    
    
      useEffect(()=> {
       
        });
    
    
    
    
    
      },[]);

//This code runs twice
 const socket = io("http://localhost:3001",
        );
    
    
        socket.on('connect', () => {
          console.log(socket.id); // 'G5p5...'
    
          socket.emit("hello", "world");
    
    
    
    
    
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
            <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
            <p>
              Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
            </p>
            <a
              className="App-link"
              href="https://reactjs.org"
              target="_blank"
              rel="noopener noreferrer"
            >
              Learn React
            </a>
          </header>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Comment: This doesn't look like it would run at all.

Comment: Check the accepted answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65037566/why-does-calling-usestates-setter-with-the-same-value-subsequently-trigger-a-co#comment114980579_65037566) question, might be useful

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does calling useState's setter with the same value subsequently trigger a component update even if the old state equals the new state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65037566/why-does-calling-usestates-setter-with-the-same-value-subsequently-trigger-a-co)

Answer (score 0):

Because the code is called on every render of your component. You should put your code to the useEffect, because you want to register handlers only once on component mount. Use effect with empty deps array is the best place as it is the same as componentDidMount in class components.

Example with ChatAPI subscription:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1