# Should I reset state only if it differs from its initial value?

Tags: performance, next.js, react-hooks, conditional-statements

I often see people resetting state at the top of event handler functions without using conditions. So I wanted to ask if there is any downside to that in regards to performance?

Example:

```
const [error, setError] = useState('')


const handleSubmit = () => {
  setError('')
}

// versus

const handleSubmit = () => {
  if (error) {
    setError('')
  }
}
```

Taking into account that React will not rerender anything if the state is set to the same value it already has, there is the question left if it takes more performance to reassign the state or to check if the initial value of the state was changed.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the language tag.

Comment: The assumption that "React will not renderer..." does not really hold (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65038885/1207195). Is the difference negligible? Absolutely.